# Axios Delete Not Working In React App But Working In PostMan/Insomnia

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, crud, mern

Axios DELETE works when I send a request through postman but on my react app it doesn't. I'm passing the _id that MongoDB assigns the entry. I'm initiating ObjectId and it still doesn't work. I also double checked if I was using the correct route, which I was.

In my app I have click function that calls SaveBook. That part I feel okay about. Let me know if I need to share something else.

SaveBook in AuthActions.js on the front end

```
export const saveBook = ({books, user, book, _id}) => {
    return function () {
        
        console.log(`This is id ${JSON.stringify(_id)}`)


          const savedIndex = books.indexOf(book);
         

        if (savedIndex >= 0) {
            console.log(savedIndex)
            axios
            .delete("/api/users/wishlist", {_id})
        } else {
            console.log(savedIndex)
            // console.log(`Adding ${book.book.title} to faves...`);
            axios
            .post("/api/users/dashboard", {book, user})
            .then(console.log("success"))
            .catch (err =>
                json(err)
            );
        }
    }
   };
```

In users.js the delete operation on the server side

```
 router.delete('/wishlist', (req, res) => {
    const db = mongoUtil.getDb();
   
    
    db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("savedbooks")
    
    .deleteOne({_id:ObjectId(req.body._id)})
    
    .then(res.json(res.data))
 });
```

Comment: I think "_id" data is in req.body.params._id

Comment: I changed it back. I forgot I tested that as a last ditch effort

Answer (score 0):

I realized req.body wasn't the correct choice for the Delete method and used url params/ req.params to send the _id. This works well.

Fixed this line in authActions.js

```
axios
    .delete("/api/users/wishlist/" + _id,)
```

Fixed these few lines in Users.js

```
 router.delete('/wishlist/:id', (req, res) => {
    const db = mongoUtil.getDb();
    
    db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("savedbooks")
    
    // .deleteOne({_id:ObjectId(req.body._id)})
    .deleteOne({_id:ObjectId(req.params.id)})
```

Comment: I have the same problem but passing the id as url params doesn't solve my problem. I'm using a PHP server. I don't think the problem comes from the server though, since it is processing requests from Postman. Can anyone help?